# How to do variable routing in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I have this problem & I am unable to find the solution for it.
This is an example of code where I am trying to route to variable URL routing

```
$routeProvider.when('/Book', {
    template: 'examples/book.html',
    controller: BookCntl,
});
$routeProvider.when('/Book/chapter01', {
    template: 'examples/chapter01.html',
    controller: ChapterCntl,
});
```

If I want to fix the url till `/Book/chapter` and `01` can be a variable. Like if user changes `02` or `03` till `100`. Do I need to write the `$routeProvider` 100 times or can be a simple solution, where I can use the number part as a variable and write single `$routeProvider` to handle `01` to `100`?

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need to add 100 seperate route definitions. You add a variable to your url template by adding `/:some_variable`, and then you are to fetch that variable by using the `$routeParams` service.

#### Example

```
$routeProvider.when('/Book/chapter/:chapterid', {
   templateUrl: 'examples/chapter-view.html',
   controller: ChapterCntl,
});
```

And then inject `$routeParams` into your controller:

```
function ChapterCntl($routeParams) {
   var chapterId = $routeParams.chapterid;

   //use the id to fetch content.
}
```

It does seem like you have a different html page for each chapter. If that is the case you can set a function to the `template` field to generate the path for the html file:

```
$routeProvider.when('/Book/chapter/:chapterid', {
   template: function(routeParams) {
      var id = routeParams.id;
      return 'examples/chapter'+id+'.html';
   },
   controller: ChapterCntl,
});
```

If that case is that you are fetching the data from an API through a service, it might be useful to be using the `resolve` field instead. The resolve field will loaded the data and be injectable into the controller. Which means that the data will be loaded before transitioning in to the new route.

```
$routeProvider.when('/Book/chapter/:chapterid', {
   templateUrl: 'examples/chapter-view.html',
   controller: ChapterCntl,

   //Will run the below function before transitioning into new route.
   resolve: {
      chapter: function($routeParams, chaptersDataService) {
         var id = $routeParams.chapterid;
         return chaptersDataService.getChapter(id);
      }
   }
});
```

And the inject the chapter into your controller:

```
function ChapterCntl($scope, chapter) {
    $scope.chapter = chapter; 
    console.log( chapter );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered UI Route Provider? You could easily use stateparams..

```
$stateProvider
    .state('book.chapter', {
        url: "/book/chapter/:chapterId",
        templateUrl: 'book.chapter.detail.html',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
          ....
        }
})
```

Sources:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing#url-parameters
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider

You could also stick with routeprovider in a slightly different way than suggested in other answers.

```
$routeProvider.when('/Book/:chapter', {
            templateUrl : { function (dynamicUrl) {
               return '/Book/' + dynamicUrl.chapter + '.html';
            },
            controller: 'ChapterCntl'
});
```